# question was protected by user of less than 1k reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, protected-questions

I was just stumbling on StackOverFlow and I found out a question that is protected by user who has a reputation of `584`, here's the link of the question

[SO: How to change sa password in SQL Server 2008 express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781365/how-to-change-sa-password-in-sql-server-2008-express)

According on this link [Protect Question](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/protect-questions):

A user must have atleast `15000 reputation` in order to protect a question.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The user that protected the question [worked for SE](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/welcome-valued-associate-dori-smith/) at the time and had moderator powers.

Comment: And it needed it; 3 spam answers about the same product.

Answer (score 0):

> A user must have atleast 15000 reputation in order to protect a question.

That is for normal users; diamond users can have any reputation, and still be able to protect questions. This is what happened in this case, as [Dori was a Community Coordinator](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/welcome-valued-associate-dori-smith/) (and, as such, a diamond user).

Since she doesn't work anymore for Stack Exchange, she is not anymore a diamond user.